# hard-coded shortcuts

Tags: c++, qt

I have asked this question on several places but I still can't figure it out.

What I am trying to do is to have a `QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_X, Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_C)` in a `MainWindow` with `QTextEdit` as a central widget.

The problem is that I have a shorcut for Cut (<kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>) and when I press <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> it doesn't work. When the focus is on a different widget the shorcut works perfectly.

I tried with overriding the `QWidget::keyPressEvent` and `QWidget::event` but it is the same.

I have one more question: if I have these two shorcuts <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> why I don't receive the signal `activatedAmbigiously()` when I press <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>? According to the Qt documentation:

> When a key sequence is being typed at the keyboard, it is said to be
>   ambiguous as long as it matches the start of more than one shortcut.

Comment: Can you tell which widget ends up swallowing the events?

Comment: I think it's the QTextEdit because it tries to run the cut action.

Comment: So when Ctrl+X is pressed, you don't want the QTextEdit to perform a cut action? Or do you want it to do the cutting, but then also have the main window receive the keypress?

Comment: Yes, I want the QTextEdit to perform a cut action when I press Ctrl+X only and QMainWindow to quit when I press Ctrl+XCtrl+C.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit of a fudge, but can't you simply work with installing an event filter on the central widget and look for the key presses that you are interested in?

The code below to me seems to do what you describe, if you press `CTRL+X` it starts a timer which upon its timeout() will trigger a `cut()` event on the `QTextEdit` (which is the `centralWidget()` of the `QMainWindow`). If instead another key event comes with a `CTRL+C` while the `CTRL+X` flag is still active, it will trigger a `close()`.

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MYMAINWINDOW_H
#define MYMAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow, private Ui::MainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0 );
  virtual bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

public slots:
  void passOnEvent();

private:
  QTimer *timer;
  bool xactive;

};

#endif
```

**mainwindow.cc**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QKeyEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent ) : QMainWindow(parent), timer (new QTimer), xactive(false)
{
  setupUi(this);
  centralWidget()->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
  if( obj != centralWidget() ) {
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
  } else  if (event->type() ==  QEvent::KeyPress ) {
    QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
    if( keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_X && keyEvent->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier ) {
      timer->start(250);
      connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(passOnEvent()));
      xactive = true;
      return true;
    } else if( xactive && keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_C && keyEvent->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier ) {
      this->close();
      return true;
    } else {
      return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
  } else {
    // standard event processing                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
  }
}

void MainWindow::passOnEvent()
{
  xactive = false;
  timer->stop();
  static_cast<QTextEdit*>(centralWidget())->cut();
}
```

While this code works for me, there could be things in it that interfere with other things you are doing. Also, I am not addressing any of the questions you had with regards to the `QKeySequence` and `activatedAmbigiously()`.

Let me know if this helps.